# How to make an optional dependency in AutoFac?

Tags: .net, autofac, default-value

I've got an interface, implementation, and target:

```
public interface IPerson { public string Name { get; } }
public class Person: IPerson { public string Name { get { return "John"; } } }
public class Target { public Target(IPerson person) {} }
```

I'm using Autofac to tie things together:

```
builder.RegisterType<Person>().As<IPerson>().SingleInstance();
```

The problem is that `IPerson` lives in a shared assembly, `Person` lives in a plugin (which may or may not be there), and `Target` lives in the main application that loads plugins. If there are no plugins loaded that implement `IPerson`, Autofac goes ballistic about not being able to resolve `Target`'s dependencies. And I cannot really blame it for that.

However I know that `Target` is able to handle the lack of an `IPerson` and would be more than happy to get a `null` instead. In fact, I'm pretty sure that all the components which rely on an `IPerson` are prepared to take a `null` it its stead. So how can I tell Autofac - "It's OK sweety, don't worry, just give me back a `null`, alright?"

One way I found is to add a default parameter to `Target`:

```
public class Target { public Target(IPerson person = null) {} }
```

That works, but then I need to do this for all the components that require an `IPerson`. Can I also do it the other way round? Somehow tell Autofac "If all else fails for resolving `IPerson`, return null"?

Comment: See also `ResolveOptional()`.

Comment: If `Person` lives in plugin, how can you register it? Where does this call goes? `builder.RegisterType<Person>().As<IPerson>().SingleInstance();`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - each plugin has a `Initialize(ContainerBuilder)` method which is called by the main application. Plugins register their components there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this syntax :

```
  builder.RegisterType<Target>().WithParameter(TypedParameter.From<IPerson>(null));
```

Unfortunately

```
  builder.Register(c => (IPerson)null).As<IPerson>();
  // will throw : Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: A delegate registered to create instances of 'ConsoleApplication17.Program+IPerson' returned null.
```

and

```
  builder.RegisterInstance<IPerson>(null).As<IPerson>();
  // will throw : Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

If you don't want to add a WithParameter for each registration, you can add a module that will do it for you

```
public class OptionalAutowiringModule : Autofac.Module
{
    public OptionalAutowiringModule(IEnumerable<Type> optionalTypes)
    {
        this._optionalTypes = optionalTypes;
    }
    public OptionalAutowiringModule(params Type[] optionalTypes)
    {
        this._optionalTypes = optionalTypes;
    }


    private readonly IEnumerable<Type> _optionalTypes;


    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);

        registration.Preparing += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Concat(new Parameter[] { new OptionalAutowiringParameter(this._optionalTypes) });
        };
    }
}
public class OptionalAutowiringParameter : Parameter
{
    public OptionalAutowiringParameter(IEnumerable<Type> optionalTypes)
    {
        this._optionalTypes = optionalTypes.ToList();
    }


    private readonly List<Type> _optionalTypes;


    public override Boolean CanSupplyValue(ParameterInfo pi, IComponentContext context, out Func<Object> valueProvider)
    {
        if (this._optionalTypes.Contains(pi.ParameterType) && !context.IsRegistered(pi.ParameterType))
        {
            valueProvider = () => null;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            valueProvider = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, all you have to do is to register your module with your optional dependencies

```
builder.RegisterModule(new OptionalAutowiringModule(typeof(IPerson)));
```

But instead of injecting a null reference which may cause a nullReferenceException. An another solution would be to create `NullPerson` implementation.

```
  builder.RegisterType<NullPerson>().As<IPerson>();
  builder.RegisterType<Target>();
```

When you have your real implementation only registered it again, it will *overwrite* the original implementation.

Comment: Well, the first option is not much better than just specifying `= null` in the parameter declaration. In fact, it's even longer. A `NullPerson` is kind of a solution, but pretty awkward.

Comment: I updated my sample to avoid registering a parameter for each registration using a module

Comment: OK, so a custom registration source. Well, I guess that's the best possible way then. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 11):

Just use optional parameters, see the following sample:

```
public class SomeClass
{
     public SomeClass(ISomeDependency someDependency = null)
     {
           // someDependency will be null in case you've not registered that before, and will be filled whenever you register that.
     }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. (Tried with the approach like `builder.Register(c => (IPerson)null).As<IPerson>();` which I need to use in my project.) -1

Comment: @AlKepp, a missing dependency is one that has simply not been registered. What you're doing is trying to force Autofac to return a null value as a dependency, which it will not do. That form of registration will always throw an exception. That isn't Yaser's fault.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* just take your dependency on `IPerson person = null` in your constructor, which is an implicit declaration of an optional `IPerson` dependency (c.f. @YaserMoradi). However, that puts you in the position of having to solidify this, now and forever after:

> "... I'm pretty sure that all the components which rely on an `IPerson` are prepared to take a `null` it its stead."

Better that this doesn't have to be a question at all.

The "[best practice](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/best-practices/)" pattern (which @CyrilDurand gives as a suffix on his answer) for this is to use a [default implementation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#default-registrations) (link upshot: Autofac will use the last registered component as the default provider of that service). If you have no other implementation coming from your plugin (registered after the default) this default will be used.

In your case, the default component should be some kind of no-op or base implementation of the `IPerson` service, where any method called will have whatever constitutes the default behavior for your application. This gives a better reuse story as well, since you can define the default behavior once and for all.

Comment: I tried that `= null` approach but it doesn't work. It still throws the same exception, regardless of that `= null` being present or not.

Comment: If it was indeed Autofac that threw the exception at resolution time, something else is going on. But even so, the better solution is using a "special case" default implementation, as noted in the second half of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Marc mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47401496/1811525), a [default implementation](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/best-practices/#use-constructor-injection) should be considered in the first place. But there are situations where this might not be appropriate for some reason. If `IService service = null` is not enough in some situation, [Adam Storr describes an alternative way](https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/optional-dependencies-with-autofac) of annotating the constructor parameter as being optional (using a feature introduced with Autofac 5.x).

The result could look like this:

```
public class Target { public Target([Optional] IPerson person) {} }
```

The `OptionalAttribute` can dynamically decide what *default* value is returned.

Note that this attribute is required for every affected constructor (which is actually something the original poster would like to avoid).

Comment: Interesting! How does an `[Optional] IService service` dependency differ from the prior "optional" dependency pattern `IService service = null`?

Comment: This is indeed a good question. I guess the power of the `ParameterFilterAttribute` based way is that the attribute can dynamically decide what value it returns. But I agree that a separate attribute seems overkill when the attribute always returns `null` when `TryResolve` could not resolve the service.